# What are security problems of this SP

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that returns value of a field sent through parameter :

```
@Field nvarchar(50),
@ID int
...

execute('SELECT ' + @Field + ' from SampleTable where (ID=' + @ID + ');');
```

I'm doing this to have one SP instead of several SP's with the same structure .
Now I'm not sure is this safe or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and [quotename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to be safe.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select '+quotename(@Field)+' from SampleTable where ID = @ID'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID int', @ID
```

Answer (score 2):

The query is not safe.

The client using the web system can drop your entire database using a SQL injection attack
by passing ' ; DROP DATABASE dbname  -- instead of id.
In case you plan to use the above query use a parametrized SQL stored procedure to prevent SQL injection attacks.

More details below :-

[How to protect from SQL injection attacks in ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: I do , this query is inside a stored procedure that takes 'Field' and 'ID' as parameters . and ID's type is set to int .

Comment: @reza - you are not protected from SQL injection just because you use a stored procedure. You are building the statement dynamically in the SP and you are open for attacks.